# Custom function: Insert object into table

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have the following function in my postgres database:

```sql
create function my_schema.create_my_book(book my_schema.book) returns my_schema.book as $$
declare
  v_book my_schema.book;
begin
  insert into my_schema.book(title, language) values (book.title, book.language) returning * into v_book;
  return v_book;
end;
$$ language plpgsql volatile;
```

This way I have to type out all the column names (`title, language`) and values (`book.title, book.language`). My book table is quite big so this will blow up my code by a lot, and once I add a column I will have to remember to add it to this function too.

Is there a way to directly insert the whole `book my_schema.book` object?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, here it is. You do not even need plpgsql to do this, plain sql will do (and works faster).

```sql
create or replace function my_schema.create_my_book(arg_book my_schema.book)
returns my_schema.book as
$$
  insert into my_schema.book select arg_book.* returning *;
$$ language sql volatile;
```

I changed the argument's name to `arg_book` in order to avoid possible ambiguity. And since the type of `arg_book` is `my_schema.book` this simple code adapts itself to table mutation and continues to work.

**To solve the id issue**

```sql
create or replace function my_schema.create_my_book(arg_book my_schema.book)
returns my_schema.book as
$$
declare
  v_book my_schema.book%rowtype;
begin
  arg_book.id := nextval('the-id-sequence-name'); 
  insert into my_schema.book select arg_book.* returning * into v_book;
  return v_book;
end;
$$ language plpgsql volatile;
```

which is pretty close to your initial function, just dynamic.

Comment: This will unfortunately lead to this error: "Error: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint"

Comment: That's right. You may add a before-insert trigger that has `NEW.id := nextval('the-sequence-name')` to `my_schema.create_my_book` to solve it. I will update my answer with an alternative.